# Question About Feeding an Array into K-Means.Fit

Tags: python, python-3.x, cluster-analysis, k-means, databricks

I'm on `databricks`; pulling in data from a *SQL Server DB*.  The data comes in fine, I selected a few numeric fields from the much larger `dataframe`, and I threw this into an array.

On this line:

```
model = kmeans.fit(dataset)
```

I am getting this error:

```
raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps,
```

Here is my code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import ClusteringEvaluator
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans


df = spark.read \
    .jdbc("jdbc:sqlxx//sqlxx.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=name_of_database", "dbo.name_of_table",
          properties={"user": "user", "password": "pwd"})


dataset = df.select('Rat', 'Cat', 'Coup', 'Mat', 'Pr', 'Sp', 'Co', 'Weight', 'DV')

dataset = dataset.fillna(0)

data_array =  np.array(dataset.select('Rat', 'Cat', 'Coup', 'Mat', 'Pr', 'Sp', 'Co', 'Weight', 'DV').collect())


# Loads data.
dataset = data_array

# Trains a k-means model.
kmeans = KMeans().setK(2).setSeed(1)
model = kmeans.fit(dataset)

# Make predictions
predictions = model.transform(dataset)

# Evaluate clustering by computing Silhouette score
evaluator = ClusteringEvaluator()

silhouette = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
print("Silhouette with squared euclidean distance = " + str(silhouette))

# Shows the result.
centers = model.clusterCenters()
print("Cluster Centers: ")
for center in centers:
    print(center)
```

When I run something similar in *Spyder/Anaconda* (just slight changes for that environment), it runs fine.  There must be something special that `databricks` needs, but I'm not sure what, exactly.

The code sample comes from the [this link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-clustering.html).

Comment: I found something here:

https://runawayhorse001.github.io/LearningApacheSpark/clustering.html

It's talking about converting the dataset to a dense vector?  Is that what I need to run things in the databricks world?  I though everything had to be in an array.